# How to save the best model for GAN

Tags: deep-learning, model, training-data, generative-adversarial-network

GAN has two sub-models: Discriminator and Generator. During training, I want to select and save the best model for them. Normally, I save Discriminator and Generator separately, then will load them for later predictions. However, I am getting confused how to define the best model for Discriminator, is it the one with lowest or highest loss?
In the theory, the Discriminator likely to enlarge the loss and try to discriminate fake and real, if so, does it mean the model with higher loss is the better one?
Thank you